# Администрирование linux: имена пользователей и защита файлов на чтение запись

Tags: bash, linux

1. Как узнать имена пользователей у которых нет пароля?
2. Как защитить файл для чтения/записи со стороны владельца/пользователя?

Answer (score 5):

1. sudo cat /etc/shadow | awk -F ':' '{ if ($2=="\!\!") {print $1} }'
2. chmod u-rwx filename.ext

тупо, зато быстро. Множество есть ньюансов и исключений, как-то

1. если пользователи не в /etc/passwd, а к примеру, в ldap или еще где, то ничего вы так не увидите - смотрите тогде через sudo getent shadow | бла бла бла
2. учитывайте еще, что человек может быть в группе которой разрешен доступ ))

Comment: А кто помешает владельцу разрешить себе доступ? Это не винды.

Comment: этого в вопросе не было)) это тема другого вопроса.